# Im using Eclipse to development on Android how can i view a Log?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have this line:

```
Log.i("----------",Arrays.toString(Locale.getAvailableLocales()));
```

This line show me a list of available languages on my device.
But the list i can see it only after i run the program and also i see it on the bottom in one of the view windows forgot wich one since iclosed it by accident but i saw it for a second in green color.

Is there any way to see this Log List array right after i run the program and also to see it better on the pc not in the device i mean like a messageBox or something ?  I mean to see it better in the Eclipse it self.

Another problem is i added in the Main.xml designer one button and one textBox but i cant drag them around. I drag them once into the right area but i cant move them they are locked where they are now. Is there any way to move them around change the location in the designer ?

This is my code:

```
package com.testotspeech;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AndroidTestToSpeechActivity extends Activity implements
        TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private Button btnSpeak;
    private EditText txtText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.i("----------",Arrays.toString(Locale.getAvailableLocales()));
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

        btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

        txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

        // button on click event
        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                speakOut();
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.CHINESE);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
                speakOut();

            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }

    private void speakOut() {

        String text = txtText.getText().toString();

        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse

Click Window > Show View > Other > LogCat

Answer (score 0):

Another way to see the logs is by running ddms.bat from android-sdk/tools. Sometimes I had problems with Eclipse not showing logs while DDMS always worked for me.

Comment: eclipse has a DDMS perspective.